# Number of independent partitions in a path of n nodes and number of partitions for a set of n-1 elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, set-partition, path-connected

I need to find a bijective proof that the number of independent partitions in a path of $n$ nodes and number of partitions of a set of $n-1$ elements are equal.

By *independent partitions* in a path we mean the partitions which create subset of nodes which are **not adjacent**.

For example, if I have the path:

$a\frac{\;\;\;\;\;\;}{}b\frac{\;\;\;\;\;\;}{}c$

the independent partitions are: $|a|b|c|$ and $|a c|b|$

$a$ and $c$ can be in the same block because they are not adjacent. So, for a path of three nodes we got 2 independent partitions. If we consider the set of $n-1$ elements (then 3-1=2) $\{a, b\}$ we get the following partitions: $|a|b|$ and $|a b|$

So we got again 2 partitions. I'm not going to show you other examples, because the equivalence is easily demonstrable empirically. But I cannot find the connection between the two type of partitions.

I thought about the calculation method for the partitions in a set (with the Stirling Numbers of the second kind) but doesn't seem the right way.

I thought also about the fact that $n-1$ is exactly the number of edge in the path, but even this way seems to lead nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bijection:**

Given a set of 'independent partitions' of a totally ordered set of elements (the independent partitions are defined in the question as a partition such that two consecutive elements are never in the same subset) let the numbers $1\ldots N$ label the elements.

The following process maps the independent partitions of $N$ elements to the partitions of $N-1$ elements.

1. Order the partitions by the smallest element in each set
2. For each element $n$, if it is in a higher partition (as defined by the ordering of partitions in 1.) than the element $n-1$, then move it down 1 partition.
3. Relabel the elements $n \rightarrow n-1$.
4. Remove the highest partition in the ordering if it is empty.
5. Remove the element $0$.

Inverting this process gives the opposite map.

**Example:**

For example, given the independent partitions of 4 elements, ordered according to 1., we perform the steps (2.), (3.) and (4.&5.) whilst highlighting when relevant the elements moved according in step (2.).

$$
\begin{matrix}
13|\color{red}{24} \\
13|\color{red}{2}|\color{red}{4} \\
14|\color{red}{2}|\color{red}{3} \\
1|\color{red}{2}4|\color{red}{3} \\
1|\color{red}{2}|\color{red}{3}|\color{red}{4}
\end{matrix}
\xrightarrow{2.}
\begin{matrix}
1\color{red}{2}3\color{red}{4}|- \\
1\color{red}{2}3|\color{red}{4}|- \\
1\color{red}{2}4|\color{red}{3}|- \\
1\color{red}{2}|\color{red}{3}4|- \\
1\color{red}{2}|\color{red}{3}|\color{red}{4}|-
\end{matrix}
\xrightarrow{3.}
\begin{matrix}
0123|- \\
012|3|- \\
013|2|- \\
01|23|- \\
01|2|3|-
\end{matrix}
\xrightarrow{4.\, \& \, 5.}
\begin{matrix}
123 \\
12|3 \\
13|2 \\
1|23 \\
1|2|3
\end{matrix}
$$